# What causes my AI to find random points on the map without picking a real target?

Tags: javascript, debugging, artificial-intelligence

### Background

I am writing an AI with basic targeting and movement. There are two types of "creatures": the active `fauna`, and the inactive targets `flora`.

### The Problem

My AI (attached to the `fauna`) first targets `flora` but it only "sees" some of the `flora`. When there are no `flora` visible to the AI, the AI will spin in circles and seemingly randomly bounce around; even if there are `flora` remaining.

What is causing only some of the `flora` to be seen? Why do the `fauna` bounce around seemingly aimlessly after they stop finding `flora`? Why do the `fauna` clump up after the code has run for a while? What causes the `flora` not to be seen?

If you need any extra information please ask.

### My attempts to fix it

My first attempt to fix the problem had some success but didn't completely fix the problem. This is when I rewrote the code using objects instead of arrays. Once I did this the targeting worked but some of the `fauna` would spin endlessly.

I then realized that it was likely that the creatures rotation wasn't comparable with the getAngle function's return. The creature's rotation could have been equivalent to the getAngle's return but wouldn't be equal (eg. 360deg ~= 720deg but 360deg != 720deg). After I fixed this it appeared to work for a while but as I ran the test with more inspection and for longer times, I discovered these issues.

I'm really not sure what would cause an issue like this but I'm very curious to find out. Thanks for any help **:)**

### Explanation of code

The code is available online at: http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/wgZqgL/

At the beginning of my code I have some `Object` prototype extensions that allow me to use objects like arrays. These are roughly equivalent to their `Array` counterparts. I do not believe these are the source of the problem but they are necessary for the program to run.

```
Object.prototype.filter = function(fn) {
  let ob = this, keep = {},
      k = Object.keys(ob);

  for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    if (fn(k[i], ob[k[i]]))
      keep[k[i]] = ob[k[i]];
  }

  return keep;
}

Object.prototype.forEach = function(fn) {
  let ob = this, k = Object.keys(ob);

  for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
    fn(k[i], ob[k[i]]);
}

Object.prototype.reduce = function(test, initialValue = null) {
  let ob = this, k = Object.keys(ob),
      accumulator = initialValue || ob[k[0]],
      i = (initialValue === null) ? 1 : 0;

  for (; i < k.length; i++)
    accumulator = test(accumulator, k[i], ob[k[i]], ob);

  return accumulator;
}
```

Next I have some helper functions for manipulating the "creatures".

```
// calculates the distance between two creatures by taking their [pos] as inputs
function getDist(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
// calculates the angle from point1 to point2
function getAngle(p1, p2) {
  return (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) / Math.PI * 180 + 360) % 360;
}

// moves the creature in the direction they are facing
function move() {
  this.pos.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
  this.pos.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
}
// rotates the creature towards the angle input by the turn speed of the creature
function rotateTowards(angle) {
  this.direction += Math.sign(angle - this.direction) * this.turnSpeed;
  this.direction = this.direction % 360;
}
// rotates the creature by the angle provided
function rotateBy(angle) {
  this.direction += angle;
  this.direction = this.direction % 360;
}
```

Now I have the targeting function. It starts by taking the creature that is running the ai, then it takes an object of the creatures to look through, next it takes the mode which currently is only able to find the nearest, finally it takes a filtering function which lets the target finder only look at flora.

The code first filters out the ones that aren't in the AI's line of sight. This is where I expect the problem to be. Next it applies the input filter (so that in my case only `flora` remain). Finally, only if there are any left in the object of creatures, the code reduces the object to only the nearest creature. If there aren't any left in the object of creatures, it returns an array with undefined.

```
function getTarget(c, of, mode = `nearest`, filter) {
  let first;

  // filter so its only the ones in view
  of = of.filter((k, t) => {
    return Math.abs(getAngle(c.pos, t.pos) - c.direction) < c.viewAngle / 2;
  });

  // filter for target type; eg. only return flora
  if (filter)
    of = of.filter(filter);

  if (Object.keys(of).length) {
    first = of[Object.keys(of)[0]];

    if (mode == `nearest`) {
      return of.reduce((acc, k, cur) => {
        let dist = getDist(c.pos, cur.pos);
        if (dist < acc[0])
          return [dist, k];
        else
          return acc;
      }, [getDist(c.pos, first.pos), first]);
    }
  }
  else
    return [undefined, undefined];
}
```

Finally I have the general AI which ties the targeting system together with the movement code. If there is a target, the creature turns and moves towards the target. If the target is within 5 pixels of creature, the creature destroys the target. Otherwise the creature turns in a positive direction, "looking" for another target.

```
function findfood() {
  let target = getTarget(this, ob, `nearest`, (k, c) => c.type == `flora`);

  this.target = target[1];

  if (ob[this.target]) {
    rotateTowards.call(this, getAngle(this.pos, ob[this.target].pos));
    if (getDist(this.pos, ob[this.target].pos) > 5)
      move.call(this);
    else {
      delete ob[this.target];
    }
  }
  else
    rotateBy.call(this, this.turnSpeed);
}
```

Here I generate an object with randomly placed `flora` and `fauna`. I use an ID system using an `Object` rather than and `Array`. All of the creatures are stored into a dynamic global object.

```
ob = {};

for (let i = 20; i > 0; i--) {
  let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000),
      type = (Math.random() > .2 ? `flora` : `fauna`);

  ob[id] = {
    type: type,
    pos: { x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width), y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) },
    direction: Math.random() * 360
  }
  if (type == `fauna`) {
    ob[id].ai = findfood;
    ob[id].viewAngle = 90;
    ob[id].speed = .8;
    ob[id].turnSpeed = 1.6;
  }
}
```

I then run the simulation in a setInterval, which calls the AI function if the creature has it. The problem isn't here either.

```
let fixedUpdate = setInterval(function() {
  Object.keys(ob).forEach((ck) => {
    let c = ob[ck];

    if (c && c.ai)
      c.ai.apply(c);
  });
}, 1000 / 60);
```

This is the code I use to display it. Its just basic canvas stuff, so the problem problem definitely isn't here.

```
let draw = () => {
  // clear canvas
  ctx.putImageData(emptyCanvas, 0, 0);

  Object.keys(ob).forEach((ck) => {

    let c = ob[ck];

    if (c.type == 'flora')
      ctx.fillStyle = '#22cc33';
    else if (c.type == 'fauna') {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#0066ee';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(c.pos.x, c.pos.y);
      // ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x + 100, c.pos.y - 50);
      // ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x + 100, c.pos.y + 50);
      ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x, c.pos.y);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(c.pos.x, c.pos.y, 100, (c.direction - c.viewAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180, (c.direction + c.viewAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    else
      ctx.fillStyle = '#424242';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.pos.x, c.pos.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

Here's the code embedded:

```js
console.clear();

Object.prototype.filter = function(fn) {
  let ob = this, keep = {},
      k = Object.keys(ob);

  for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    if (fn(k[i], ob[k[i]]))
      keep[k[i]] = ob[k[i]];
  }

  return keep;
}

Object.prototype.forEach = function(fn) {
  let ob = this, k = Object.keys(ob);

  for (let i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
    fn(k[i], ob[k[i]]);
}

Object.prototype.reduce = function(test, initialValue = null) {
  let ob = this, k = Object.keys(ob),
      accumulator = initialValue || ob[k[0]],
      i = (initialValue === null) ? 1 : 0;

  for (; i < k.length; i++)
    accumulator = test(accumulator, k[i], ob[k[i]], ob);

  return accumulator;
}



function getDist(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
function getAngle(p1, p2) {
  return (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) / Math.PI * 180 + 360) % 360;
}

function move() {
  this.pos.x += this.speed * Math.cos(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
  this.pos.y += this.speed * Math.sin(this.direction * Math.PI / 180);
}
function rotateTowards(angle) {
  this.direction += Math.sign(angle - this.direction) * this.turnSpeed;
  this.direction = this.direction % 360;
}
function rotateBy(angle) {
  this.direction += angle;
  this.direction = this.direction % 360;
}

function getTarget(c, of, mode = `nearest`, filter) {
  let first;

  // filter so its only the ones in view
  of = of.filter((k, t) => {
    return Math.abs(getAngle(c.pos, t.pos) - c.direction) < c.viewAngle / 2;
  });

  // filter for target type; eg. only return flora
  if (filter)
    of = of.filter(filter);

  if (Object.keys(of).length) {
    first = of[Object.keys(of)[0]];

    if (mode == `nearest`) {
      return of.reduce((acc, k, cur) => {
        let dist = getDist(c.pos, cur.pos);
        if (dist < acc[0])
          return [dist, k];
        else
          return acc;
      }, [getDist(c.pos, first.pos), first]);
    }
  }
  else
    return [undefined, undefined];
}

function findfood() {

  let target = getTarget(this, ob, `nearest`, (k, c) => c.type == `flora`);

  this.target = target[1];

  if (ob[this.target]) {
    rotateTowards.call(this, getAngle(this.pos, ob[this.target].pos));
    if (getDist(this.pos, ob[this.target].pos) > 5)
      move.call(this);
    else {
      delete ob[this.target];
    }
  }
  else
    rotateBy.call(this, this.turnSpeed);

}




ob = {};

for (let i = 20; i > 0; i--) {
  let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000),
      type = (Math.random() > .2 ? `flora` : `fauna`);

  ob[id] = {
    type: type,
    pos: { x: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width), y: Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) },
    direction: Math.random() * 360
  }
  if (type == `fauna`) {
    ob[id].ai = findfood;
    ob[id].viewAngle = 90;
    ob[id].speed = .8;
    ob[id].turnSpeed = 1.6;
  }
}

console.log(ob);



let ctx = canvas.getContext(`2d`);
let emptyCanvas = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

let draw = () => {
  // clear canvas
  ctx.putImageData(emptyCanvas, 0, 0);

  Object.keys(ob).forEach((ck) => {

    let c = ob[ck];

    if (c.type == 'flora')
      ctx.fillStyle = '#22cc33';
    else if (c.type == 'fauna') {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#0066ee';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(c.pos.x, c.pos.y);
      // ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x + 100, c.pos.y - 50);
      // ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x + 100, c.pos.y + 50);
      ctx.lineTo(c.pos.x, c.pos.y);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(c.pos.x, c.pos.y, 100, (c.direction - c.viewAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180, (c.direction + c.viewAngle / 2) * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    else
      ctx.fillStyle = '#424242';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.pos.x, c.pos.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();



let fixedUpdate = setInterval(function() {
  Object.keys(ob).forEach((ck) => {
    let c = ob[ck];

    if (c && c.ai)
      c.ai.apply(c);
  })
}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas height="1000" id="canvas" width="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: _"When there are no flora visible to the AI, the AI will spin in circles and seemingly randomly bounce around; even if there are flora remaining.

What is causing only some of the flora to be seen?"_ , _"Otherwise the creature turns in a positive direction, "looking" for another target."_ What effect do `rotateTowwards()` and `rotateBy()` calls at `findFood()` have at object?

Comment: @guest271314 `rotateTowards()` changes the direction that the creature (a child of the global object) faces closer to the angle supplied. `rotateBy()` just changes the direction by a fixed amount. Both functions apply a modulus of 360 so that the value is always [0, 360). This in turn affects the view of the creature.

Comment: Yes, is that the described effect of issue at Question? What is expected result? What is affect of returning `[undefined, undefined]` from `getTarget`? Would `target.target` be defined at `findFood()`?

Comment: Would `rotateBy()` be called recursively if `ob[this.target]` is `undefined`?

Comment: @guest271314 The rotation works as desired. Each time the AI is called (once every 60 seconds) the creature looks for a target regardless of whether `ob[this.target]` is `undefined`, therefor `rotateBy()` wouldn't be called recursively.  
  
If you run the simulation for around 30 seconds, the `fauna` run out of  `flora` that they see. Then they form clumps. If you'd like me to record a gif of the problem, I'd be happy to.  
  
I return the `[undefined, undefined]` from `getTarget()` so that I'm able to access `target[1]` even if there is no target.

Comment: `gif` image would probably not provide further depiction than codepen. What is expected behaviour? Can you reduce piece to least amount of `javascript` necessary to reproduce issue; that is, without using `requestAnimationFrame`, to be able to call and inspect functions in succession without recursively calling entire process again?

Comment: @guest271314 I would be able to reproduce the overall issue without the canvas code but then you wouldn't be able to see the display. This is the only way to see the issue, as there are no errors produced by running the code.

Comment: I've done some additional testing and it appears that the `fauna` see the `flora` but only for a very small amount of time, which causes their jittery behavior. I still don't see what is causing it in the code though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135998/discussion-between-ckh4-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my code. I in `getTarget()`, when I was getting the first of the possible targets (`of[0]`), I stored first as the reference to the creature rather than the ID of the creature.

To fix it, I had to store the ID instead by removing the reference to the object. I changed:

```
first = of[Object.keys(of)[0]];
```

To:

```
first = Object.keys(of)[0];
```

This caused problems in the rest of the code of `getTarget()` because I was trying to get properties attached to the creature's object, instead of the creatures ID. I fixed that by changing:

```
}, [getDist(c.pos, first.pos), first]);
```

To:

```
}, [getDist(c.pos, of[first].pos), first]);
```

This gave me the finished `getTarget()` of:

```
function getTarget(c, of, mode = `nearest`, filter) {
  let first;

  // filter so its only the ones in view
  of = of.filter((k, t) => {
    return Math.abs(getAngle(c.pos, t.pos) - c.direction) < c.viewAngle / 2;
  });

  // filter for target type; eg. only return flora
  if (filter)
    of = of.filter(filter);

  if (Object.keys(of).length) {
    first = Object.keys(of)[0];

    if (mode == `nearest`) {
      return of.reduce((acc, k, cur) => {
        let dist = getDist(c.pos, cur.pos);
        if (dist < acc[0])
          return [dist, k];
        else
          return acc;
      }, [getDist(c.pos, of[first].pos), first]);
    }
  }
  else
    return [undefined, undefined];
}
```